# Application not run without check System IP Address

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

My question is that i have a Windows Desktop Application. And i want how i will make a condition check that this PC System IP is equal to this IP. Then my Application runs. And otherwise it must show the message.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look something like the following:

```
private bool CheckIPAddress(string addressToCheck)
{
    bool addressFound = false;
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

    foreach (var address in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (address.ToString() == addressToCheck)
        {
            addressFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (!addressFound)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Address not found")!
    }

    return addressFound;
}
```

Hope it helps!